# FTP upload directory and subdirectories in Perl

Tags: perl, ftp

I am trying to FTP a directory that has subdirectories with files and images using Perl.

I tried using `$ftp->rput()` under `Net::FTP::Recursive`. But this uploads all files under local current working directory.

Is there a way to give the path of local directory and all folders and files are uploaded. Please guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your own working directory temporarily.

> ```
> rput ( [FlattenTree => 1] [,RemoveLocalFiles => 1] )
> ```
>
> The recursive put
>   method call. This will recursively send the local current working
>   directory and its contents to the ftp object's current working
>   directory.

Perl's [builtin `chdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chdir.html) can be used to change the directory. Use the [Cwd module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html) to get the current one if you need to go back.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use Net::FTP::Recursive;

# ...

# get the current directory
my $old_current_dir = getcwd();

# change directory to the one you want to upload
chdir('path/to/updloaddir');

# upload
$ftp->rput();

# change back
chdir($old_current_dir);
```

Comment: Need another advice. May be not the right way to do here. I have zip file created using Perl. I upload this via FTP again , which works fine. But whine I download the zip and try to open or extract it says 'invalid'. Any idea?

Comment: @Virus ask a new question for that please.

Comment: sure. will ask a new one